# pnpm monorepo resolve nested dependencies

Tags: svelte, monorepo, sveltekit, pnpm

I have a monorepo using pnpm and svelte, the structure of the repo is like the following

```
.
├── packages
│   └── app1/
|        └──package.json { "devDependencies": { "components":"workspace:^0.0.1" }}
│   └── components/
|          └──select.svelte (which use svelte-select package)
|          └──package.json
├── ...
├── package.json
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
└── ...
```

I have added the “components” package to “app1” using the “pnpm add” command and I have used the select component  inside the index page of the “app1” project.
When I run the “app1” package using “pnpm run dev” it returns

```
<Select> is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules
```

The problem is “app1” does not resolve the dependencies of “components” package (svelte-select)
And when I added “svelte-select” as a dependency in “app1” the error was gone.
Is there any way to not include “svelte-select” as a dependency in “app1” and only add it in the “components” package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you required svelte-select in app1?

Comment: yes, if I added "svelte-select" in "package.json" of "app1" the error was gone, but I don't want to to that since it is required by "components" package

Comment: Does your components' `package.json` contain a `svelte` field? Is `svelte-select` in `dependencies` or `devDependencies`?

Comment: I tried to add `svelte-select` in both places `dependencies` and `devDependencies` in `components`' package.json` and both places didn't work

Comment: If you are importing svelte-select in the code of app1, then you'll need to add it to dependencies. It doesn't matter that it is in the dependencies of a dependency.

Comment: I have created a wrapper for `svelte-select` inside `components` package, and then import the wrapped component in `app1` using `import { MySelect } from '@mylib/components';`, I don't want to add `svelte-select` to `package.json` of `app1` since it is a dependency for `components` package only

Comment: Hi @JonyAshkar, I also encounter the same issue. Do you manage to solve it?